# Can't get email sending with HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to make my own HTML / CSS form processed with PHP. The form has no errors that I can tell, just something going wrong with the PHP. I am not receiving the message from the form. I'm new with PHP and trying to learn about it. Any help is appreciated.

HTML form:

```
<form class="grn-background" action="processing.php" method="post">
      <label for="fullname">Full Name</label>
      <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
</form>
```

processing.php file

```
$full_name = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST{'message'};

$to = 'services@brentnicolet.com';
$subject = 'BNWS Contact Form Submission';
$form_message = "$message";
mail($to, $subject, 'From' . $email);


echo 'Thank you' . $full_name . '. We have received your message and will respond within the next 24 - 48 hours.';

?>
```

Comment: your mail's header contains a typo, which is causing your mail to not be delivered, or rejected altogether.

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer for minimum requirement to run php-mailer
also note if you are using localhost - it will not work, as well as on github. It works when you have it on the hosted website.

Comment: It is hosted on my website. Still not getting it to work.